# Table to 2NF in Talend

Tags: talend

How can I get a table to 2NF in Talend?

Currently I have:

```
Marc   Mayr    12/12/1980    Someitem
Marc   Mayr    12/12/1980    Somethingelse
Steven Ming    08/09/1981    Completelydifferent
```

So I want to split person and item data into two separate tables.
How can this be done using Talend? (Remark: I don't have a primary key yet, but I can use a combination of name and birthday - already checked for distinct values.)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, I'm not that familiar with the Talend workflow. Right now, I just used aggregateRow on the name and birthday column, so this is my first table. Now I need to generate a primary key on this table and then also attach it to the corresponding rows when building the second table... IMHO this must all be done in one subjob, otherwise a cannot guarantee primary key consistency.

Comment: You should consider elaborating your question a little bit. Where is your data coming from ? What is your destination ? What is the destination table schema ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

tFileinput -> First_Name,Second_Name,Year -> tMySQLOutput (persons) (set the table to have an ID with auto increment as the primary key)

```
tFileinput           ->     
                        tMap -> Item
tMySQLInput(persons) ->
```

So basically there are 2 different step:

- Step1: create the persons table
- Step2: map the persons the the inputfile and populate the orders table.

This can be done via SQL as well.

Comment: Yes, I finally solved this with SQL only.
My intention was to do this in one simple step without direct use of SQL because I have to perform this multiple times and in different database engines. However, this also worked with a somewhat neutral SQL script.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Andreas , Can you please share with us your talend project with your example and your problematic solution, thanks in advance.